# Error displaying database within a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I am displaying my database in a `ListView`. I used a `Button` named `find geopoint` for displaying the database. when I click on it, the application crashes. Here is the stack trace:

```
08-25 17:03:11.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cortes/com.cortes.Display}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 1 col -1 failed
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 1 col -1 failed
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:363)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at com.cortes.Display.onCreate(Display.java:116)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
08-25 17:03:11.338: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8373):     ... 11 more
```

Here is my code:

```
c = db.query(Geo_Create_Table, new String[ {"_id","latitude","longitude","address"}, null,null, null, null, null);

x1 = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
y1 = c.getColumnIndex("latitude");
z1 = c.getColumnIndex("longiitude");
w1 = c.getColumnIndex("address");
while(c.moveToNext()) {
    a = c.getInt(x1);
    b1 = c.getString(y1);
    c1 = c.getString(z1);
    e = c.getString(w1);

    results.add(a+"" + " " + b1 + " " + c1 + " " + e); 
}
ArrayAdapter<String> a11=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
lv.setAdapter(a11);
```

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cortes"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application 
              android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
              android:label="@string/app_name">

              <uses-library 
                   android:required="true" 
                   android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

              <activity 
                      android:name=".Cortes"
                      android:label="@string/app_name">
                      <intent-filter>
                          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                      </intent-filter>
              </activity>
              <activity 
                      android:name=".Display"
                      android:label="@string/app_name"
                      android:launchMode="singleTask">
                      <intent-filter>
                           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                      </intent-filter>
               </activity>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: the latitude,longitude,address are the column names whose values i retrieved from a bundle

Comment: i posted the manifest file pls help me

Comment: Can you please paste your create table query?